# Laravel 5 with Postgres SQL

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, pdo, laravel-5

I’m working on Laravel 5 with postgres as database. I’ve configured postgres  9.4 and pgAdmin III and these are working normally. When I try to run migrate it is giving me error:

> [PDOException]
>   could not find driver

This is my database.php

```
'default' => 'pgsql',

'pgsql' => [            'driver'   => 'pgsql',          
                        'host'     => '127.0.0.1',          
                        'database' => 'fms',            
                        'username' => 'postgres',           
                        'password' => 'root',           
                        'charset'  => 'utf8',           
                        'prefix'   => '',           
                        'schema'   => 'public',         ],
```

Initially I though, it was due to configuration of postgres on windows 7 but I tried with plain php it works perfect

```
<?php
   $host        = "host=127.0.0.1";
   $port        = "port=5432";
   $dbname      = "dbname=fms";

   $db = pg_connect( "$host $port $dbname user=postgres password=root"  );
   if(!$db){
      echo "Error : Unable to open database\n";
   } else {
      echo "Opened database successfully\n";
   }
?>
```

I’ve enabled **php_pgsql** and **php_pdo_sql** in wamp as well. I’m not sure how to fix this on laravel 5.

Comment: In your `php.ini` can you uncomment the `extension=pdo_pgsql.so` ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As you said you already choosed Default Database as Postgres SQL

```
'default' => 'pgsql',
```

It is a must that you need to uncomment the pdo and postgres shared object in your php configuration settings `(php.ini)`

i.e., You need to uncomment the following lines in your php.ini

```
extension=pdo_pgsql.so
extension=pgsql.so
```

**Note :**

Don't forget to stop and start your `apache` after doing this changes (or `php-fpm` if using that instead).

Comment: I ran `sudo apt install php7.4-pgsql` https://www.php.net/manual/en/pgsql.installation.php#119801 and then `service php7.4-fpm restart` but I still get "Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_pgsql'"

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem with Laravel-WAMP-PostgreSql driver not found exception. I even successfully established direct connection to Postgre as you have, but with no luck with the "php artisan migrate" command.

After long research I found out that there are multiple php.ini files in which "extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll" and "extension=php_pgsql.dll" are comented out.

The solution is (of course) to uncoment the extensions in the following files:

- ~/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.*/php.ini
- ~/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.*/phpForApache
- ~/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.*/php.ini.install
- ~/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.*/php.ini-development
- ~/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.*/php.ini-production
  and
- ~/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/php.ini

** You can leave off the "php.ini-development" and "php.ini-production" (don't need to uncoment these files).

Answer (score 3):

Like @jeff said, this is probably caused by not setting `DB_CONNECTION=pgsql` in the `.env`-file. The `.env`-file has MySQL preconfigured, so you **must** edit this file.

Answer (score 3):

You have to make DB related changes in

1. config/database.php
2. .env file

and other settings in

- php.ini settings

If you are still getting error, then clear cache and config

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

It should work now!

Comment: I stopped the command running 'php artisan:serve' and then I run your commands and again run 'php artisan:serve' and that worked!. Thanks very much.

Comment: I had everything right, I was 100% sure cause I tried using external scripts, the part of clearing cache and config did it! thanks

Answer (score 1):

Run this command to easily uncomment the lines extension=pdo_pgsql.so and extension=pgsql.so from php.ini

```
sed -ri -e 's!;extension=pdo_pgsql!extension=pdo_pgsql!' $PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini

sed -ri -e 's!;extension=pgsql!extension=pgsql!' $PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini
```

If you do not have the drivers already installed, or it gives error like unable to load dynamic library PGSQL run this:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpq-dev && docker-php-ext-install pdo pgsql pdo_pgsql
```

This will install the pgsql and pdo_pgsql drivers.

Answer (score 0):

you gotta modify .env file , then go to config>database.php and change the default to pgsql, and also in all your models file you need to change $protected $connection= 'pgsql'.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using PHP7.3 and this worked for me, I forgot this:

```
apt-get install php7.3-pgsql
```

Everything runs smoothly afterwards.  Just use whatever version of PHP you are using.