# Migration error in laravel 5.5 with PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, laravel-5

Created a new application in laravel 5.5 and done configuration with postgres

[image]

also set default db driver pgsql in database.php , but while running laravel migrate artisan command getting below error

[image]

but connection working in core php

[image]

i didnt getting what is the wrong with laravel with PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

[Laravel 5 + PostgreSQL: "Database [postgres] not configured." Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35111806/laravel-5-postgresql-database-postgres-not-configured-error)

Check and make sure the pdo postgress driver is installed and loaded correctly.

and quoting from

[Laravel 5 with Postgres SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480385/laravel-5-with-postgres-sql)

> As you said you already choosed Default Database as Postgres SQL
>
> 'default' => 'pgsql', It is a must that you need to uncomment the pdo
>   and postgres shared object in your php configuration settings
>   (php.ini)
>
> i.e., You need to uncomment the following lines in your php.ini
>
> extension=pdo_pgsql.so extension=pgsql.so Note :
>
> Don't forget to stop and start your apache after doing this changes.

Comment: Hi Giovanni thank you for your response , i already enabled php_pgsql and php_pdo_pgsql

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed, Actually my PostgreSQL version was 9.6 and i updated in to 10.1 now laravel 5.5 with PostgreSQL 10.1 migration working like a champ :)

[image]