# Driver could not found in laravel 5.6 ,Iam using pgsql (pgadmin4) for database

Tags: php, laravel

`pdo_pgsql` and `pgsql` extensions are enabled.
postgres bin path already set to global.

i tried to connect core php with pdo,pgsql its working fine.

but when trying php artisan migrate from the command line in laravel 5.6 actually its not working.

[image: Illuminate\Database\QueryException : could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = public and table_name = migrations)]

Comment: [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30482261/4648586) done already?

Comment: yes done. but i am using wamp on window 10 so I uncommented php_pdo_pgsql.dll and php_pgsql.dll

Comment: hmm, thats weird, you said using pdo directly is ok but laravel can't. the stacktrace however shows that it can't get pgsql driver.. can you check that `libpg` (dot dll for windows),  is exist on php bin and apache bin directory?

Comment: I fixed that error. error coming because in phpForApache file php_pdo_pgsql and php_pgsql were commented so I uncommented these now all things working fine. :) thanks a lot for help.

Comment: where is this *phpForApache* located? perhaps you can answer your question yourself :)

Comment: No i cheked that link which you gave "these steps".
So i found solution there . 
~/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.*/php.ini
~/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.*/phpForApache ( location of file)